# Is there a way to launch an app from the lock screen?

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 as a media PC using Kodi. What I would like is for anyone to be able to launch Kodi from the lock screen. Right now I have to login and the launch Kodi, which leaves all the files accessible to anyone else. If the app could be launch from the lock screen I won't have to worry about files being moved or deleted by someone else.

The Kiosk mode on Chromebooks comes to mind, but I would like for the user to go back to the lock screen when the app is closed.

Would it be possible to do this through by adding an icon to the lock screen? Either on the screen somewhere or on the task bar at the top. I also like the idea of a keyboard shortcut, but an icon would work better for my purposes.

Comment: If you are only worried about the files, you could use a separate account. IIRC, 16.04 supports guest accounts, would that be an option?

Comment: @danzel Does Ubuntu 16.04 support multiple accounts being logged in at the same time like Windows? I have stuff running on my account that other PCs on the network rely on. If Ubuntu supports this, I'll consider it as a backup plan to what I'm looking for.